# Transform type of columns by name in df with for loop

Tags: r

I try to transform the type of specific columns in my df. Therefore I create a vector with the names of columns I would like to change and then loop through it. But instead of changing the type I create a new cloumn "i" with this code.

Why this doesn´t work?

```
iris <- tbl_df(iris)

cols.to.change = c("Petal.Width", "Species")

for (i in cols.to.change) {
  iris <- transform(iris, i = as.character(i))
}
```

When I do it without the loop it works.

```
iris <- transform(iris, Petal.Width = as.character(Petal.Width))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may transform all columns in the list to character without needing a `for` loop, like this:

```
iris[cols.to.change] <- lapply(iris[cols.to.change], as.character)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about subsetting the columns, coercing them to whatever class you wish and overwriting the result into your original data.frame?

```
cols.to.change = c("Petal.Width", "Species")

for (i in cols.to.change) {
  iris[, i] <- as.character(iris[, i])
}

> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```